# Override a function inside a model

Tags: magento2.4, override-model

I want to override a function inside the model, but it doesn't work.
I just want to make correction on existing function, not adding a new function.

I did some google, some suggestion ask to use plugin method.

But I am not writing a new function. I want to make correction of existing function. What should I do?
When I was using override function method. the error message is below.

```
Type Error occurred when creating object: Ahead\AdvancedReviews\Block\Email\Review\RequestForm, Argument 5 passed to Ahead\AdvancedReviews\Block\Email\Review\RequestForm::__construct() must be an instance of Ahead\AdvancedReviews\Model\Product\Resolver, instance of (vendor)\(module)\Model\Product\Resolver given, called in /var/www/html/Magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121
```

Comment: You try executing this magento command in command line = bin/magento setup:di:compile to regenerate the generated files again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error probably means you only just forgot to compile your class which means the current version in generated doesn't have the same parameters as in your code.

TO fix that you just have to compile if you are in production mode. If you are in developer mode then simply  getting rid of generated with setup upgrade should do the job.

If you want to replace a function code by an other other.

What you need to do is a preference (a plugin would be more for adding a behaviour not correcting it).

di.xml

```
 <preference for="Vendor\Module\Your\Class"
            type="Magento\Module\Your\Class" />
```

Then you extend the class and just rewrite the method as you want in the new class.

Comment: I am in developer mode and also removed generated  folder files, same error message still exist? what can I do next? thanks

Comment: Thanks! its works now! just have issue with the class extend

Comment: @PaulFan If you use some tools like php storm, you have a shortcut if the class is extended, start typing `__` and the construct method will appear. Storm will extend automatically the constructor with the parent call, this way you are sure not to have any mistake in the parameters.